# What are the components of VXN?

Tags: options, volatility, index

What are the *exact* components of VXN -- the [volatility index for NASDAQ-100](http://www.cboe.com/index/dashboard/vxn#vxn-overview)?

The CBOE page links to the document for VIX, which clarifies the exact set of front-month near-the-money SPX options used for VIX calculation and how weights are assigned (basically in the Black-Scholes-esq way). But I can't find any similar document for VXN. What is the formula for VXN?

Comment: "The same formula and methodology used to calculate the VIX Index is applied to the VXN". You look at all options of a given maturity and select all those that meet requirements (essentialy a non-zero bid price) (Page 6). And the formula is also the same.

Comment: @noob2: Do you mean NDX options are used? Did you fit VXN values to confirm or is there an official source confirming that?

Comment: I believe it is these options https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/phlx/NDXProductSheet.pdf but I have nver traded them or done the calculations.

Comment: @noob2: Thanks. I'll confirm it by fitting NDX option data to VXN value when I get a chance. In the meantime, if you come across or remember any official document confirming that VXN uses NDX options, could you share it here please?